# Swift UIBarButtonItem is hidden but works

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have an problem with an UIBarButtonItem. If I protect my app with an ViewController, to authenticate the User through Touch ID, then the UIBarButtonItem in the Navigation Controller is hidden.

The code in the AppDelegate:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let touchIDonoff = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "touchIDActive") as! Bool!

    if touchIDonoff == true {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TouchIDViewController") as! TouchIDViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = loginVC

    }
    return true

}
```

Code in the ViewController for TouchID-Request:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.touchIDrequest()
    }

@IBAction func buttonTouchID(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    touchIDabfrage()
}



func touchIDrequest() {
    let authenticationContext = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?


    if authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Please authenticate", reply: { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in

            if success {
                self.navigatetoAuthenticatedVC()
            } else {
                if let evaluateError = error as? NSError {
                    print(error)
                    /*let message = self.errorMessageForLAErrorCode(errorCode: evaluateError.code)
                    self.showAlertViewAfterEvaluatingPolicyWithMessage(message: message)
                    */
                }
            }


        })
    } else {
        showAlertViewForNoBiometrics()
        return
    }
}

func navigatetoAuthenticatedVC() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoggedInVC") as! UITabBarController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    }

}
```

If I hit the hidden UIBarButtonItem it works and bring me to the next ViewController and when I go back, the UIBarButtonItem is visible.

What did I wrong? Any help please?

Best regards

[image: Button is hidden]

[image: Button is visible]

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Attribute Inspector]

Comment: Can you show the attributes inspector on the button?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: The idea here is you have to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` property to `false`, but it works really weird and I couldn't make it work. I can suggest you a workaround, if you like.

Comment: you need to disable bar button item .or  do nil bar button if you want hide it